# Print A0 sized map

Tags: printing, software-recommendations

Currently I am exploring an option/software to print A0 sized maps on web and also on desktop, can you guide me if any software support this printing option.

Note: ESRI will be expensive therefore I need an alternative, I have Autodesk Map guide studio 2014 license.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with _"print A0 sized maps on web"_?

Comment: This is usually about printer drivers not GIS software. The rastering GIS>Print is only limited to the amount of memory. There is RIP software out there for commercial printing posterjet is a good one from experience http://www.posterjet.com/en/

Comment: thank you for your replies lavarider - my client wants an option to be built on the web application which would facilitate him to print large city based maps in size A0 whenever required, currently the option prints low resolution map I need a high resolution map to be printed.

Answer (score 4):

I have produced good quality A0 maps from both ArcGIS and QGIS.  Some GIS licence I have seen do limit the size of plot depending on licence but not those two and there will be pleny of other free/low cost options to explore such as Idrisi, SAGA etc.  On this note you may want to consider something like Mapnik or other renderer.

It is not down to the GIS software so much as the capabilities of your printer (or whether you can outsource the printing).  Bear in mind that a full colour A0 map will most likely be a very large file and so you need to consider download time on the web, given that you will want at least 300-600 dpi.  At this resolution QGIS can sometimes struggle, I don't know why, so you may have to lower the resolution.

The capability of your computer to render the image and the plotter's memory limits also become a factor at this size.  The standard memory which most plotters seem to come with is less than I have found adequate for quality A0 plotting even if the plotter can handle the paper size in theory.  Memory is cheap though, so for a few quid, you can max out the memory of the plotter.  Also, a better graphics card may help at the rendering end of things.  So, on reflection, getting a good quality A0 plot is a combination of factors, the least of which is the GIS software.

Answer (score 1):

For the desktop QGIS will support A0 and any other export size most people need.

Answer (score 1):

For Web printing you could try:

1) MapFish Print: Java based framework that allows web printing up to A0 (PDF only)

2) QGIS Server: a WMS 1.3 compliant map server with 'GetPrint' request capability that allows the client to request printable output in PNG or PDF format. A good guideline document is available here: http://gis.uster.ch/dokumentation/publikationen/qgis-server-and-web-client-foss4g-2013-slides

My bet is that QGIS Server will be the easiest to set up and deploy your data as WMS and do the required web printing.

Answer (score 0):

I use FPDF for printing online, where I can print design, text, chart, table, but I've a problem with OpenLayers.

For the element of the map I print all part with QGis Atlas and archive output in online folder, that load on FPDF and mix it with design, text, ...