# Printing Large Maps Causing Adobe to Crash

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, layouts, printing, plotter

I'm having trouble printing some large maps (ANSI 34x44) on a Canon inmagePROGRAF TM-300 plotter. I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro, version 2022.001. The maps are part of a Map Series in ArcGIS Pro, but exported individually. Most of the maps print fine, but others seem to cause Adobe to crash during the flattening process.

What I've tried so far:

- Testing most settings in ArcGIS export layout settings/Adobe Printer Settings/Plotter Printer settings
- PDF compression

Comment: How large are the files? Is there any correlation between file size and what maps crash Adobe? Does printing the same maps crash Adobe on other computers, or just this one?

Comment: There does seem to be a correlation. Pretty much every file above 10mb fails during the flattening process; file sizes range from approx 5mb to 25mb. Trying the flattener preview also causes Adobe to crash, as well as trying to complete flattening in the PDF fixups menu. I'll try and find another computer to print from here at the office, but I believe my colleagues were having the same issue from their computers. Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: If it's not a computer-specific issue, my guess is it's a bug caused by an update on ESRI or Adobe's end. For example, one of the early updates to ArcGIS Pro 3.0.x caused exported pdfs to show up as blank pages in Adobe, and it took some fiddling to find a combination of export options that worked until ESRI fixed the bug in the next update.

Comment: We had to use RIP software (ArcGIS>Adobe Illustrator>PostJet) to print very large plots. This reduced the issues printing from ArcGIS.  see older post https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/90824/276

Comment: Those don't seem that large. Are you using the Save as Reduced feature in Adobe.

Comment: Can you print the map from ArcGIS Pro directly instead of going through the pdf export process?  If you export your pdf without layers does that print?  Can you print the pdf as image prior to flattening?  Although a longshot you could check  your layers for geometry errors since those can affect printing.